# Adding a Form into My HTML Keeps Function in Javascript File from Working

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

For some inexplicable reason, whenever I add `<form></form>` around the three lines above the blockquote, the text inside the blockquote stops being replaced with the text returned from the flask server. I don't have any problem that needs to be solved, as I can easily work around this. I am just curious as to why this issue exists in the first place.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='CSSsheets/SBPstyle.css') }}" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="expertiseReq" placeholder="leave blank for any skill level" />
    <input id="locationReq" placeholder="leave blank for any location" />
    <button id="gatherNames">Click to Get List of Player Names</button> 
    <blockquote id="playerNamesGoHere" class="properly_sized_blockquote">No Player Names Loaded</blockquote>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JSscripts/SBPscript.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.properly_sized_blockquote {
    border: solid;
    border-block-width: 20px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const gatherPlayersButton = document.getElementById('gatherNames');
const areaForPlayerNames = document.getElementById('playerNamesGoHere')
const summon_players = () => {
    let eR
    let lR
    if (document.getElementById('expertiseReq').value == "") {
        eR = "None";
    } else {
        eR = document.getElementById('expertiseReq').value
    };
    if (document.getElementById('locationReq').value == "") {
        lR = "None";
    } else {
        lR = document.getElementById('locationReq').value
    };
    let tagsString = eR + "," + lR;
    fetch(`/battle?tags=${tagsString}`, { method: "GET" }).then((response) => response.text()).then((text) => {
        areaForPlayerNames.innerText = text;
    });
};

gatherPlayersButton.addEventListener("click", () => summon_players());
```

Flask Server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from static.SNEKfiles import SpaceShipGame
import json


game_app = Flask(__name__)

@game_app.route('/') 
@game_app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("HTMLPage1.html")

@game_app.route('/battle', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def battle():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        gathering_player_requirements = request.args.get('tags')
        if gathering_player_requirements != None:
            print(gathering_player_requirements)
            skill_requirement = gathering_player_requirements.split(",")[0]
            location_requirement = gathering_player_requirements.split(",")[1]
            gathering_player = SpaceShipGame.Player()
            gathered_player_names = gathering_player.obtainAllPlayerNames(skill_requirement, location_requirement)
            return gathered_player_names
        else:
            return render_template("SingleBattlePage.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons default to `type="submit"`. When you add the `<form>`, the button suddenly has a form to submit in addition to triggering its click handler.

Consider:

```js
document.querySelector("form")
  .addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted");
  });

document.querySelectorAll("button")
  .forEach(e =>
    e.addEventListener("click", e =>
      console.log("button clicked")
    )
  );
```

```css
form {
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button>Submit and trigger click</button>
</form>

<button>Outside of form--just click</button>
```

While it's not clear what your `<form>` element you added looks like (what are its `method` and `action` attributes?), it sounds like you just want some clarity on the scenario, so hopefully this is sufficient. Adding `type="button"` to the button will prevent it from triggering the form submission, so whatever your behavior was before should be unaltered.

```js
document.querySelector("form")
  .addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted");
  });

document.querySelectorAll("button")
  .forEach(e =>
    e.addEventListener("click", e =>
      console.log("button clicked")
    )
  );
```

```css
form {
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button">
    Inside of form--trigger click only since type="button" was added
  </button>
</form>

<button>Outside of form--just click</button>
```

See [Button Type In HTML: Here's Why You Should Always Declare It](https://html.com/attributes/button-type/) for details.

---

A few other suggestions for reducing your code smell and adhering to best practices:

- Use `kebab-case` for CSS classes and ids (or at least be consistent).
- Use `camelCase` for JS functions and variables.
- Use `snake_case` for Python functions and variables.
- Avoid injecting script snippets inline throughout the template. Use modules if possible and load the script(s) at the end of the document. This keeps the HTML and JS separate and ensures the DOM is loaded fully before you begin manipulating it. All of this should make debugging easier.
- Use closures around your scripts to prevent variable name clashes.
- Avoid `let` when you can refactor to `const`. `const` provides stronger guarantees of reassignment and generally makes the logic easier to understand and debug.
- Use [`===` instead of `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) to avoid weird false positives due to type coercion.
- Avoid building query string payloads with concatenation or other custom delimiters: `let tagsString = eR + "," + lR;`. Use something like [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) into separate parameters or switch the route to a POST and use a JSON payload. If the user provides a comma, your code will likely misbehave.
- Check the response from all `fetch` calls to make sure it was OK and handle any errors if it wasn't.
- Folders, files and HTML pages should be lowercase.

Comment: Thank you for all of the advice! It's really hard to keep all the variable naming conventions straight, as I've gone through Python, Java, and Javascript and at this point I just guess at the convention and hope it makes sense. I've never heard of a triple equals sign comparison before, I'll have to look that up in more detail.